MUI X - Datagrid - remove the MuiDataGrid-filler component
I've just noticed the existence of an extra filler space at the bottom of the grid. How can i get rid of it?

It turns to be this component:

I've tried setting its height to 0 and removing its borders. However, the vertical scroll shows up when I tried doing that. Isn't there any more elegant way to remove that element?
          "& .MuiDataGrid-filler": {
            height: "0px !important",
            border: "0px solid !important",
          },


Try using hideFooter in DataGrid. If this doesn't resolve please provide a code snippet or create a sandbox for this.

The examples on MUI demo page wrap the DataGrid with Box component that has a specific height like <Box sx={{ height: 400, width: '100%' }}>.
If you remove this wrapper Box component or remove its height property, the filler div will be removed.
You can take a look at this StackBlitz for a live working example of two datagrids one with the filler (with Box) and the other without the filler (without Box).
Note: If the datagrid shows a horizontal scroll, the filler will be visible anyway.

Interesting, although I might need to wrap the table within a container to control its height... mm..
